# React children with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having trouble with setting proper types for react children.

```
export const recursiveCloneChildren = (
  children: React.ReactNode,
  handleChildChange,
  disableContent: boolean,
) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (!isObject(child)) {
      return child;
    }

    let childProps = {
      ...child.props,
      disabled: child.props.disabled || disableContent,
    };

    const requiredOrValidatableChildProps = {
      ...childProps,
      checkValidationState: handleChildChange,
    };

    if (child.props.required || child.props.validatable) {
      childProps = {
        ...requiredOrValidatableChildProps,
      };
    }

    if (child.props.children) {
      childProps.children = recursiveCloneChildren(child.props.children, handleChildChange, disableContent);
    }

    return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
  });
};
```

I am getting this error

> Property 'props' does not exist on type '{} | ReactElement<any, string
> | JSXElementConstructor> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
> Property 'props' does not exist on type '{}'.

I tried to set types for child directly ( React.ReactChild ), and showed another error on children.
How can it be solved?

Comment: What is  ` React.Children.map`  ? Did you mean  `children.map(child => {return something..])`

Comment: Normally you just pass children through to be rendered like `{children}` which is typed as `React.ReactNode`. This component is _very_ non idiomatic. What does this component do? How is it used?

Comment: @SanishJoseph, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap

Comment: @AlexWayne it's just not a component, it's a helper function.

Comment: I am recursively cloning children inside a Form component, which will handle Form validation and child validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really like what you're trying to do, because if I found it in a codebase I'd be really confused.

But to answer your question. The `child` argument in the function passed to `Children.map` is of type `ReactNode`. This is the most general type, meaning you can end up with pretty much anything that can be a valid child. I actually don't know if your code is going to work but considering you want to access props, I'm assuming what you want is to make sure you're operating on `ReactElement`. In that case, your `isObject` check is not exhaustive enough. What you need is a type guard.

So the quick and dirty option is to write your own type guard and something like this is actually enough:

```
function isReactElement(child: React.ReactNode): child is React.ReactElement {
  return isObject(child) && 'props' in child;
}
```

and then instead of

```
if (!isObject(child)) {
  return child;
}
```

you just do

```
if (!isReactElement(child)) {
  return child;
}
```

and it works. However probably a better idea is to use `react-is` library which is an official, Facebook-maintained library and it's widely used in many React libraries and it does basically exactly what you want but the checks are significantly better than what I proposed above. In your case you'd want to use `isElement`, the same way I showed above. Just make sure to install `@types/react-is`, too.